# Error creating ivf_sq8h index refer to pymilvus documentation

Tags: indexing

I refer to [pymilvus documentation](https://pymilvus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#milvus.Milvus.create_index) to create the `IVF_sq8H` index and I keep getting an error as shown in the picture. I am using `Milvus version 1.0`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Milvus with the GPU version? If not, the error as your picture will appear.

Comment: No, I use the cpu version